# Why is the [phonegap] tag a synonym of [cordova]?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags

Recently on Stack Overflow I tried to add the [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap) tag. Upon saving, the tag had been replaced with the [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova).

These two tags have very different representations. Phonegap != Cordova and vice versa.

So my question is, why is this so?

Comment: The tag wiki entry seems to think the two are related.

Comment: I think [tag:cordova] should be a synonym of [tag:phonegap], not the other way around. **PhoneGap** is the currently promoted name (because, well, it's catchy!), and *Wikipedia* redirects *Apache Cordova* to *PhoneGap*. A *Google* search reveals that **Cordova** only vaguely references the platform (it has other meanings) while **PhoneGap** directly takes you to the official website, Wikipedia page, Twitter account and many resources directly related to the platform.

Comment: I have created a meta to separate them again, it has 20 votes already, but I don't know how much does it need before it's taken into account http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337612/remove-phonegap-as-synonym-of-cordova-tag-and-make-it-independent-again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404523/should-i-use-phonegap-or-cordova

The explanation there sounds like the differences are minimal (and PhoneGap is based on Cordova) and mostly not development-related. So most likely having two separate tags would just cause confusion because - no offense - chances are good that lots of users of those frameworks would not know how to tag the question properly.

Comment: So the takeaway I get from that is that the two are different bit we dumb it down for convenience sake. - good enough for me.

Comment: But what about the developers who just started learning phonegap? this will just confuse them.. ALOT!!  [Link](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/). and also the link you posted is broken (I mean the post is deleted).

Comment: I think there's an important difference between then since PhoneGap actually includes other stuff like integration with the PhoneGap Build service. PhoneGap uses Cordova much like Safari (and formerly Chrome) use WebKit. In addition Cordova is owned/trademarked etc by the Apache Software Foundation while PhoneGap is Adobe.

Comment: This is like merging Chrome into Webkit.

Answer (score 2):

The PhoneGap folks agree with you even though the Meta Stack Overflow powers don't. See the PhoneGap blog: [PhoneGap, Cordova, and what’s in a name?](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/).

I've called it PhoneGap for years, and actually had to go look up what Cordova was when the tag was automgically changed.