# Please undo tag merge of [cordova] and [phonegap]

Tags: discussion, support, tags

There has been a [merge request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137732/tag-merge-request-phonegap-and-cordova) about this and the accepted and high voted answer was **not to merge**. Still the merge was done [status-completed].

A [lot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186637/why-is-the-phonegap-tag-a-synonym-of-cordova) [of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190518/why-was-my-tag-silently-replaced-with-another-one) [people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143693/main-tag-of-a-question) [complained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212638/cannot-add-certain-tag-to-question) about this issue because this merge is simple **wrong**.

It is like merging Chrome into Webkit.

Yes, there has been confusion about the two names when Cordova was new but this [has been cleared](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/).

So please stop this merge.

Comment: Ok, looks like everybody agrees. Who do we proceed in this case?

Comment: It's been one month now and nothing happend. It tried to ask a [general question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224218/howto-unmerge-two-tags) about how this can be done but that was closed. So what now?

Comment: This is going to be increasingly important as Phonegap and Cordova start to show more differences with Adobe integrating their Build service into the Phonegap CLI.

Comment: I made a proposal to separate the tags, please, upvote https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337612/remove-phonegap-as-synonym-of-cordova-tag-and-make-it-independent-again