# Howto unmerge two tags?

Tags: support, tags

If a wrong tag synonym has been created and was used for some time. How can both tags be separated again?

Comment: Painstakingly, carefully, and with concerted effort. Manual labor.

Comment: @Emracool sure, but *what* has to been done and *how*? A general question about how to unmerge two tags is hardly the same as discussion about if two specific tags should be ummerged.

Comment: @Emracool: As long as the tag synonym is active, concentrated effort and manual labor won't do anything.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: By bringing attention to that post? Post a bounty on it, bump it by commenting on it, etc.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: Try starting a bounty, perhaps?